# Будет ли работать jasper reports на linux сервере?

Tags: linux, centos, shell, jasperreports

Существует ли возможность работать с jasper reports или с другим open source репортинговым движком из командной строки без GUI или web-интерфейса? Если кто-нибудь сталкивался, не могли бы вы описать как производить установку в данном случае?

Answer (score 1):

Скажу лишь о jasper reports.
[JasperReports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library) - библиотека с открытым исходным кодом позволяющая генерировать отчеты.

Данная библиотека написана на java, а значит её можно использовать на всех операционных системах, официально поддерживаемых oracle.

Насколько мне известно сама библиотека не поддерживает CLI (Command Line Interface)

Вы можете написать приложение, которое будет выполнять необходимые вам комманды.